# How to convert IMP to NSValue with Swift?

Tags: swift, nsvalue

[image]

I want convert the implementation to  NSValue, but it's err.

In Objective-C, can use this line to convert:

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:implementation]
```

but in Swift, how to convert?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: I want to store the implementation to check something. thanks.

Comment: But in Swift you can just store the Imp. That NSValue stuff is just so you can pass the Imp where an ObjectiveC object is expected. But in Swift it's already any object. So why bother converting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, it needs an `UnsafePointer`, not a `COpaquePointer`. So convert it:

```
let impValue = NSValue(pointer: UnsafePointer(imp))
```